# How would one scan a large, untrusted file?

Tags: malware, antivirus

I've recently started to convince relatives to upload anything they download to Virus Total, to help them be more safe when downloading stuff.

However, I have recently come across an installer for a game that is about 500MB large. Virus Total only supports uploads up to 128MB.

How can I ensure this file is safe to install?

Comment: To be pedantic, which is actually a good thing in security, you cannot "ensure" the file is safe. What you're trying to do it be "reasonably sure" it is safe ;-)

Comment: I understand there is no such thing as perfect security, but being able to check if 28 / 59 malware scanners identify a file as potential spyware is good enough for me.

Comment: The answer below from @Daisetsu touches on it but I'll echo the sentiment in a comment: people usually don't just happen upon 500mb files, they are intentionally sought after and if it's sought after, it should be from a trusted [legitimate] source. AV is not great at detecting malice in extremely large files. **TLDR:** Consider the source as a barometer in your quest for reasonable assurance, or just detonate it on a separate machine first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may not be aware of this, but VirusTotal saves the files that you upload.  Businesses that have a subscription to VirusTotal can download those files you uploaded, it's part of the terms of service.  I wouldn't upload anything potentially sensitive that you don't want the entire world seeing.

While VirusTotal is indeed a useful service, I don't see it being beneficial to scan everything you encounter.  Assuming you're running Windows, any of the big players in the AntiVirus game such as Windows Defender, should be sufficient most of the time.

Is there a reason you're worried about this game installer?  Is it from a legitimate source, or is it something you grabbed off a P2P service?  Things such as games which unpack giant executables aren't as likely to be caught by AntiVirus.   There's a lot more space to hide something malicious that seems innocuous.

For something that size, I would recommend running in a sandbox.  Cuckoo will analyze files and executables dynamically.  Sandboxie doesn't analyze files, but rather provides isolation, so if a program is malicious they won't be able to touch the rest of the computer.

Comment: @daisestu, I wanted to get the tool you mentioned but "cuckoosandbox.org" is detected as "malicious" by Clean MX on Virustotal, therefore, I'm not sure it's safe: am I looking at the wrong url or the antivirus detected a 'false positive', in your opinion?

Comment: @franz1 Cuckoo is just one of many sandboxes. I wouldn't personally be surprised that *one* antivirus engine didn't like the site, they often flag anti-malware as malware. It's an open source project that's been around for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

Large [legitimate] files, generally have a checksum provided by the manufacturer for a number of reasons:

- Ensure the download completed successfully and in it's entirety
- Ensure the download is from the manufacturer in it's intended (unmodified) form

I'd hunt for a checksum from the vendor and try to match the hashes up. Acceptable hashes are SHA256 and greater. *MD5 and SHA1 have known collisions and as such  will be deprecated soon*.

As a second option, you can detonate on an isolated host before running on your intended system. Sandboxes can be effective for **some** malware, but more and more malware is keen to detect if it's being run in a sandbox and will not detonate under certain conditions.

Comment: You can also submit that hash to VirusTotal (the Search tab) and you will see the report on that file it it was submitted by another user. I think business users may be able to bypass the file size limit (although I don't have first hand knowledge of that)